# How to hide the Arrows from a number input MUI TextField in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

I currently have a react-hook-form with some fields. One field is a `<TextFields />` from mui/material ([Link](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/)). This one is of type "number" and I want to hide the arrows from the number input.

#### Code

Code snippets from my `DynamicFormComponent.tsx` file:

```js
<TextField
    name="my name"
    label="my label"
    defaultValue={0}
    InputProps={{
        type: "number",
    }}
    style={{
        WebkitAppearance: "none",
        appearance: "none",
        MozAppearance: "none",
    }}
 />
```

#### Problem / Question

I want to get rid of the arrows on the right side of the TextField but my approach so far doesn't work.

I know that this pure html way works, but I can't find a way to convert that to my ReactJS component.
`<input type="number" value="5" style="-webkit-appearance: none;>`.

[image: Picture of the arrows I want to hide]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this like so:

```
<TextField
    name="my name"
    label="my label"
    defaultValue={0}
    InputProps={{
        type: "number",
 sx: {
    '& input::-webkit-outer-spin-button, & input::-webkit-inner-spin-button': {
        display: 'none'
     },
     '& input[type=number]': {
        MozAppearance: 'textfield'
      },
    }
    }}
   
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to do it with `styled-component` as it makes application supper clean and easy to maintain. It would help you to override MUI base UI to transform it as you wish

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const TextBox = styled(TextField)`
  /* Chrome, Safari, Edge, Opera */
  input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
  input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    margin: 0;
  }

  /* Firefox */
  input[type=number] {
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
  }
`;
```

now you can use it like

```
<TextBox
    name="my name"
    label="my label"
    defaultValue={0}
    InputProps={{
        type: "number",
    }}
/>
```